# Qt- Change opacity of QPixmap

Tags: c++, css, qt, opacity

How to change opacity of QPixmap?

I've set an image as background actually I want to change its opacity, Here is my code:

**Call.h:**

```
private:
    QPixmap m_avatar;
```

**Call.cpp:**

```
void Call::resizeEvent(QResizeEvent *e)
{
    QPalette pal = palette();
    pal.setBrush(backgroundRole(), m_avatar.scaled(e->size(), Qt::IgnoreAspectRatio, Qt::SmoothTransformation));
    setPalette(pal);
}
```

I've changed *resizeEvent* function, but it doesn't change background's opacity.

```
void Call::resizeEvent(QResizeEvent *e)
{
    QPixmap result_avatar(m_avatar.size());
    result_avatar.fill(Qt::transparent);
    QPainter painter;
    painter.setOpacity(0.5);
    painter.begin(&result_avatar);
    painter.drawPixmap(0, 0, m_avatar);
    painter.end();
    QPalette pal = palette();
    pal.setBrush(backgroundRole(), result_avatar.scaled(e->size(), Qt::IgnoreAspectRatio, Qt::SmoothTransformation));
    setPalette(pal);
}
```

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not using local `QPainter` object. According to [QWidget Events](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#events):

> `paintEvent()` is called whenever the widget needs to be repainted.
>   Every widget displaying custom content must implement it. **Painting
>   using a `QPainter` can only take place in a `paintEvent()` or a function
>   called by a `paintEvent()`.**

Here it works:

```
void Call::paintEvent(QPaintEvent *)
{
    // create a new object scaled to widget size
    QPixmap result_avatar = m_avatar.scaled(size());

    QPainter painter(this);
    painter.setOpacity(0.5);
    // use scaled image or if needed not scaled m_avatar
    painter.drawPixmap(0, 0, result_avatar);
}
```

---

**Update for paiting on pixmap case**

If it is needed only to paint with some opacity on a pixmap using `QPainter`, the opacity must be set only after `QPainter` activation by `QPainter::begin()`. So, after changing the order the pixmap `result_avatar` has two images (one resized with opacity 1 and original pixmap on top with opacity 0.5):

```
QPainter painter;
painter.begin(&result_avatar);
painter.setOpacity(0.5);
painter.drawPixmap(0, 0, m_avatar);
painter.end()
```

Comment: This stands only when drawing onto a widget, he is drawing onto a pixmap, you can draw onto a pixmap from wherever you want.

Comment: The author tries to set palette to widget with pixmap texture resized to widget size. The key in this question is "set an image as background actually".

Comment: I think the "actually" is actually part of the "actually I want to change its opacity". He is not painting on a widget outside of its paint event, he sets a palette, I logically assume setting the palette will invoke the default paint event. There is NOTHING it the doc that says the palette needs to be set in the paint event method.

Comment: @ddriver Thanks for pointing that indeed the main problem is painting on a pixmap with opacity. I updated my answer by explanation how to fix the issue.